# Memoria Libre y Total C++

Tags: c++

Estoy buscando una función para poder revisar la memoria total y la memoria libre desde DevC++, aplicable en un codigo orientado a objetos y que pueda usarse en una class para estructuras como `Listas` y `Arboles`.

Si la pregunta es muy larga o tiene muchas respuestas les agredecería mucho que me dijeran un libro u otro lugar donde pueda consultar tales datos.

Comment: En este caso, el IDE no tiene nada que ver con lo que necesitas. La memoria total y libre depende del sistema operativo no del IDE usado para desarrollar la aplicación.

Answer (score 3):

Repuesta original de [Travis Gockel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254306/travis-gockel)

Puede usar [sysconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html) en sitemas tipo Unix.

```
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned long long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    long pages = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    return pages * page_size;
}
```

Para sistemas basados en windows [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589(VS.85).aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>

unsigned long long getTotalSystemMemory()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
    status.dwLength = sizeof(status);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&status);
    return status.ullTotalPhys;
}
```

[**Pregunta traida de SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513505/how-to-get-available-memory-c-g?noredirect=1&lq=1#2513561)